# android app/server connection problems

Tags: android, sockets, ip

basically, I want my android app to talk to a server; however, the server will change ip address - how do I get the app to pick up on this and adjust the ip address its sending to accordingly?

better wording: I am running a server on a local network, whose IP may change. How can I have my Android app detect the server and connect to it?

NOTE: I can't use DNS because the DNS may not update for 24 hours, and I need it to be updated instantly

Comment: Isn't this what DNS was invented for? Use a domain name?

Answer (score 0):

As Paul said in the comments, you need DNS.

You could try [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/), it is free.

Answer (score 0):

Set a static IP on the server or setup a DNS record.  DynDNS is a personal favorite.

I'd personally avoid the static IP route but it's OK for testing ...